# Moving Objects Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make some interactions with some images on my site. I want to let the possibility to user of clicking on a image, holding it and then drag it everywhere he wants it on the page. Is this possible using only Javascript, HTML5 and CSS3?

*PS: I need it to run on iPhone Mobile Safari*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be possible. This jQuery Mobile plugin seems to support what you need:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/mobiledraganddrop

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to implement drag and drop using only Javascript, see [here](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/mk/column2/).

However, it is not possible to implement this on mobile safari because it will interpret the drag operation as a scroll.